# Get a running count of group over time in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr

Ok so we have some pretty standard data that looks like this with a date and user id column, but the id can occur multiple times in a day:

```
id               Date
as7fyaisdf       2017-11-08
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-08
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-08
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-08
2984oinrv7       2017-11-08
as7fyaisdf       2017-11-09
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-09
2984oinrv7       2017-11-09
9asjenorin       2017-11-09
```

I want to get a running count that shows the cumulative number of times a given id has occurred over time. But I only want it to count a single day once. So it would look like this in this case:

```
id               Date           running_count
as7fyaisdf       2017-11-08     1
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-08     1
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-08     1
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-08     1
2984oinrv7       2017-11-08     1
as7fyaisdf       2017-11-09     2
p98ashdfp9       2017-11-09     2
2984oinrv7       2017-11-09     2
9asjenorin       2017-11-09     1
```

I feel like this probably involves the rle() function or data.table's rleid(), but I haven't been able to crack it.  I'd like to do this within the tidyverse if possible, but open to other options in the R universe. Would like to keep this in any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could group by `id` and get the `row_number`:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df %>%
   left_join(distinct(.) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(running_count = row_number()))

          id       Date running_count
1 as7fyaisdf 2017-11-08             1
2 p98ashdfp9 2017-11-08             1
3 p98ashdfp9 2017-11-08             1
4 p98ashdfp9 2017-11-08             1
5 2984oinrv7 2017-11-08             1
6 as7fyaisdf 2017-11-09             2
7 p98ashdfp9 2017-11-09             2
8 2984oinrv7 2017-11-09             2
9 9asjenorin 2017-11-09             1
```

Comment: Your data is different than the original example from OP's post. Why is that?

Comment: I'm really sorry, that's my fault I changed it after I realized that it needed to take into account an id occurring multiple times on the same day

Comment: @www the data was changed

Comment: @Matt It is alright. I could not see your edit history for some reasons. All good.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about `data.table`:

using `rleid`

```
dt[order(id,Date),running_count:=rleid(Date),by=id][]
```

or joining with `unique`, like the tidyverse solution, which used `distinct()`

```
dt[unique(dt)[,running_count:=1:.N, by=.(id)], on=.(id, Date)]
```

Both option result in this output:

```
           id       Date running_count
1: as7fyaisdf 2017-11-08             1
2: p98ashdfp9 2017-11-08             1
3: p98ashdfp9 2017-11-08             1
4: p98ashdfp9 2017-11-08             1
5: 2984oinrv7 2017-11-08             1
6: as7fyaisdf 2017-11-09             2
7: p98ashdfp9 2017-11-09             2
8: 2984oinrv7 2017-11-09             2
9: 9asjenorin 2017-11-09             1
```